# TypeError: (intermediate value)[type] is not a function

Tags: css, angularjs, sails.js, angular-chart

I am trying to display a simple chart following the guide here:
http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

I am using sails.js, angular, bootstrap and angular-chart.js

When I load the app, I get a blank image where a chart should be. I see this error in chrome dev tools:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value)[type] is not a function
at createChart (angular-chart.js:175)
at Object.fn (angular-chart.js:118)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14308)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14571)
at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1455)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4203)
at doBootstrap (angular.js:1453)
at bootstrap (angular.js:1473)
at angularInit (angular.js:1367)
at angular.js:26304
```

Please forgive me but I don't know why that error is popping.

I have tried endless amounts of variations of the code below and feel this version is the closest I have gotten to a working sample.

View:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/angular-chart.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="DashboardModule" ng-controller="BarCtrl">
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" data="data" labels="labels"></canvas>

<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/Chart.Core.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script src="/js/private/dashboard/DashboardModule.js"></script>
<script src="/js/private/dashboard/DashboardController.js"></script>
</body>
```

Module:

```
angular.module('DashboardModule', ['chart.js']);
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('DashboardModule').controller("BarCtrl", function ($scope) {

$scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
$scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];

$scope.data = [
  [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
  [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
];
});
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you include the call stack with your error, but from looking at your code, one thing I do notice is you're trying to define DashboardModule twice. When you want to add a controller to an existing module you don't specify the dependency array. So for your controller:

angular.module('DashboardModule').controller("BarCtrl", function ($scope) {

$scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
$scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];

$scope.data = [
  [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
  [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
];
});

Comment: I added the call stack and made the changes to the controller. I am still getting the same result.

Comment: I'm going to try to replace all the minified .js with the full code and see what happens. Hopefully the call stack is more descriptive at least.

Comment: OP Updated with some more helpful call stack information

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the missing part was adding these two dependencies perhaps: 
-- [chart.js](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js) 
-- [angular-chart.js](https://github.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts)

working version is here: https://jsfiddle.net/cwLja39j/ 

FYI: for jsfiddle, github files can be added as "External Resources" by running them through [rawgit.com](https://rawgit.com/) first.

---

Markup:

```
<div ng-app="DashboardModule" ng-controller="BarCtrl">
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" data="data" labels="labels"></canvas>
</div>
```

JS :

```
angular.module("DashboardModule", ["chart.js"]).controller("BarCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];

  $scope.data = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  ];
});
```

(used Chrome, no errors seen in console)

Comment: You are correct.  I incorrectly used "ChartCore.js". instead of "Chart.js".

Once I replaced that file, without changing anything else from the code above, everything worked perfectly. This is 100% my fault as this dependency is clearly documented.

Answer (score 0):

It may be version issue ,Use Chart.js Version: 1.1.1

Comment: THis should be a comment